# Windows BT settings changes state from "Connected" to "Paired", instead of "Connected" to "Connected music, audio" for my Bluetooth Earphone

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, connection

I am developing an app in UWP for connecting my Bluetooth earphone device. I am using `DeviceWatcher` to serve the connection purpose. some few line of code to understand my procedure to connect with my device is as follows -

```
blDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceToConnectId);
.
//some other conditions
.
rfcommDeviceServicesResult = await blDevice.GetRfcommServicesForIdAsync(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(new Guid(serviceUUID)), BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
.
//if we get rfcommDeviceServicesResult.Service.Count > 0
.
deviceServices = rfcommDeviceServicesResult.Services[0];
streamSocket = new StreamSocket();

await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(deviceServices.ConnectionHostName, deviceServices.ConnectionServiceName);
dataWriter = new DataWriter(streamSocket.OutputStream);
dataReader = new DataReader(streamSocket.InputStream);
```

I have similar app for Android already. both Android app and UWP app were connected with the same device previously. now, I launched Android app and connected my earphone with the app. Launched UWP app too. as the earphone is connected with Android app, its showing disconnected state in UWP app with a "Connect Again" button. I clicked on the button to test the connection. Here is what happened -

```
1. Disconnected from Android App
2. Starting to connect with UWP App
3. Windows BT Settings jumped from "Paired" to "Connected"
4. Data receiving was complete
5. After some seconds Windows BT Settings jumped from "Connected" to "Paired" automatically
```

in my UWP app I am using `deviceWatcher` to handle my connection module. `DeviceWatcher.Update` event is fired when this happens. I implemented auto reconnection with the help of `DeviceWatcher.Update`. and `(bool)deviceInfoUpdate.Properties["System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected"]`becomes `false`, resulting instant disconnection

And as it seems there are three states in windows BT settings for my earphone. `Paired`, `Connected`, `Connected music, audio`. If windows BT settings is not showing `Connected music, audio` then I can't listen to music/sound via my earphone.

My questions are -

1. Why are there three states?
2. Why did Windows BT Settings jumped from "Connected" to "Paired" automatically? is this Windows OS limitation? is there any easy way to fix this?

NB: Its not a device side issue. I tested the other way around. from UWP to Android. but this issue didn't occur